# Divergence of power series at endpoints using Abel's Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

I have the following homework:

Let $P(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$ be a power series with finite radius of convergence $r > 0$ such that $P(r)$ diverges and $a_k \geq 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow r-} P(x) = \infty$$

My attempt at a solution:

We have shown Abel's theorem in class. So I know that $P(x)$ is continuous at $x = r$. Shouldn't it follow immediately then that $\lim_{x \rightarrow r-} P(x) = P(r) = \infty$, because $P(r)$ diverges ?

Because there are $5$ marks for this question it certainly won't work this way. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Abel's theorem is almost no use here. Check assumptions for Abel's theorem again. It requires $P(r)$ to be convergent. So, writing the notation $P(r)=\infty$ is also invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $M>0$, there is $N>0$ such that 
$$
\sum_{k\leq N} a_kr^k \ge M. 
$$

Consider
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow r-}\sum_{k\le N} a_k x^k=\sum_{k\leq N} a_k r^k \geq M.
$$

Since $a_k\geq 0$, for any $0\leq x <r$,

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k \geq \sum_{k\leq N} a_k x^k
$$
Now, we take $\liminf_{x\rightarrow r-}$ both sides, then
$$
\liminf_{x\rightarrow r-}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k \geq \liminf_{x\rightarrow r-}\sum_{k\leq N} a_k x^k = \lim_{x\rightarrow r-}\sum_{k\leq N} a_k x^k \geq M.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow r-}  P(x)=\infty.
$$

Comment: Yes you're right. I can't use Abel's Theorem here. I don't even know how I am supposed to find a solution like this on my own without any clues. Thanks for your answer anyways.